# How to load all the mappers into HIVE table?

Tags: hive

Hello Below is the use case:

Below are the sqoop generated files for the table statewise testing details:

$ hadoop fs -ls /STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS_23_Nov/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS
Found 5 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup          0 2020-11-23 15:38 /STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS_23_Nov/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup      19674 2020-11-23 15:38 /STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS_23_Nov/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS/part-m-00000
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup      19716 2020-11-23 15:38 /STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS_23_Nov/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS/part-m-00001
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup      18761 2020-11-23 15:38 /STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS_23_Nov/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS/part-m-00002
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup      20176 2020-11-23 15:38 /STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS_23_Nov/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS/part-m-00003

I would like to load all of them into table in HIVE ...

i am unable to do so ...

HIVE :
load data '/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS_23_Nov/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS/part-m-00000' into table STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS;

Fails :

FAILED: ParseException line 1:10 missing INPATH at ''/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS_23_Nov/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS/part-m-00000'' near ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are missing `INPATH` in `LOAD DATA` statement. So try the command like below

```
load data inpath '/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS_23_Nov/STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS/part-m-00000' into table STATEWISE_TESTING_DETAILS;
```

Also Sqoop is capable to moving data directly to Hive. This way you can make Sqoop to do the `load data` function or even the Hive table creation.

Check out this: -

1. https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive
2. https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.0/bk_data-access/content/using_sqoop_to_move_data_into_hive.html